# How much CAD should I have if I want to travel to Japan?

Tags: air-travel, budget, japan

For a city such as Osaka or Tokyo and to stay there about a week max, what would the total cost be?

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but how long is a piece of string? Staying in a hotel? A hostel? What areas? What activities? Eating out or in 7-11? It's a highly subjective question, and unfortunately that doesn't fit in the rules in the [help]. Please do edit if you can and flag to reopen.

Comment: As an addendum, I would suggest you take Japanese Yen as there aren't too many places that will accept Canadian Dollars in Japan.